TableView AutomaticDemension doesn't work(Swift
I wanted to adjust my tableview cell height, so I wrote this code :
self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 200

But it failed due to my poor autolayout. I have no idea what the problem is.
Below is my autolayout code of the tableview cell.
 NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            numberImageView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 20),
            numberImageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.topAnchor, constant: 10),
            numberImageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 20),
            numberImageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 20),
            
            descriptionLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: numberImageView.trailingAnchor, constant: 15),
            descriptionLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: -15),
            descriptionLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.topAnchor, constant: 10),
            
            descriptionImageView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerXAnchor),
            descriptionImageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: descriptionLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: 10),
            descriptionImageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100),
            descriptionImageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100),
        ])

I tried to find the missing constraints, but I think there is no problem.

there should be constraint warning printed in debug console, can you share that one?

None of the views added are pinned to bottom of the view, In order for a view to be able to calculate it's height based on content inside, there must be a ladder of constraints which connects it from top to bottom. In your case if you add bottom constraint, Your cell will be able to get dynamic height.
try adding this constraint at the end of your array
descriptionImageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: 0)

It will pin the imageview to bottom as well. So the hierarchy will be
TopAnchor -> DescriptionLabel -> DescriptionImageView -> BottomAnchor

I think you mean descriptionImageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(...) and it works! thank you!

yeah sorry, I updated the answer

The problem is cell don't know what is the bottomAnchor, so it must be taking the default height.
You should have
self.contentView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: descriptionImageView.bottomAnchor, constant: 10)

I added constant 10 as there has to be spacing between 2 cells.

Now, there is another issue with self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 200
This will cause problem if you have paging in the tableview and your tableview cell height is more then 200.
E.x. You set self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 1. Now if paging is there, you will find say 4 cells in screen but load more (indexPath.row) will get called as estimated height is 1, so 100 cells will get loaded & paging will get called...
So I suggest to keep self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = heightOfTheScreen safe side.
